# how to insert gt table into a ggplot2 line chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, charts, gt

I want to insert the gt table to a ggplot2 line chart

here is my code for the line chart code below

here is my dataset named value to create the line ggplot2 line charts

| Month | Facevalue | pct |
| --- | --- | --- |
| January | 36,434,456 | -19 |
| February | 37,434,457 | 13 |
| March | 34,424,458 | 4 |
| April | 36,595,759 | 1 |
| May | 34,434,460 | -6 |
| June | 44,434,461 | 54 |
| July | 22,434,462 | -32 |
| August | 16,434,463 | 12 |
| September | 44,434,464 | 1 |
| October | 31,434,465 | 15 |
| November | 14,434,466 | -4 |
| December | 11,434,467 | 9 |

```
p<-ggplot(data = value, aes(x=Month, y=Facevalue, group=1 , fill = Month))+
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_point(color = "#0000FF" , shape = "diamond" , size = 8)+
  geom_text(aes(label = Facevalue), vjust = -0.5)+
  scale_y_continuous(label=scales::comma) +
  xlab("Monthly Face Value") + 
  ylab("Month")+
  labs(title =  "Polaris Bank Face value Trend from January to August 2021", element_text(face = "bold", colour = "white", size = 20))+
  theme_gray(base_size = 11)+
  theme(
        panel.border = element_rect(linetype = "dashed", fill = NA),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#583759"),
        axis.line = element_line(size = 3, colour = "#0000FF"),
        axis.text = element_text(colour = "#400134"),
        axis.ticks = element_line(size = 0.5),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = rel(1.5), angle = 90),
        axis.ticks.length.y = unit(.2, "cm"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "red"),
  axis.ticks.length.x = unit(-.25, "cm"),
  axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = .3, unit = "cm")),
  legend.justification = "top")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = unit_format(unit = "M", scale=1e-6))

p + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1000000, 100000000))
```

which gives the chart in the image below

[image]

and my gt table goes like this
#create a table and named it growth
growth <-data.frame(
Note=c("Average success rate :","Average processing duration:","Average daily count:",
"Total count processed:"),
June=c({""},{""},{""},{""}),
July=c({""},{""},{""},{""})) #create a data frame

```
 #insert the growth data frame in gt table
gt(growth)%>%
   tab_header("Point")%>%
  tab_options(table.width = pct(50))%>%
  tab_options(heading.background.color = "#7D0552", table.background.color = "lightcyan",
        table.font.size = px(14), table.font.color = "#000000", table.font.weight = "bold",
        )%>%
  cols_align(align = "center")%>%
  tab_style(
    style = cell_borders(
      sides = "all",
      color = "#7D0552",
      weight = px(2),
      style = "solid"),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = everything(),
    rows = everything()))%>%
  cols_width(
    Note ~ px(200),
    ends_with(c("e","y")) ~ px(100),
    everything() ~ px(60))
```

which result in this gt table image

[image]

so how do I insert the gt(growth) into the ggplot2 line chart to give
The desired output image below

[image]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I just added sample data to create the ggplot2 line charts
and for the table, the sample data is also there, ill be glad if you can assist me 
thanks.

Comment: Checkout Patchwork. I think you'll find an example on this page of a plot and chart combo. https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/assembly.html

Comment: One approach would be to output both the graph and table as image files then composite them as one output file with `magick`, an R library that gives you decent access to the very capable ImageMagick toolset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to this problem by using the patchwork package

the name of my table I want to insert is called my_table

my plot is p

```
library (patchwork)
wrap_plots(p,my_table)
```

which in return gives me the solution to the problem